# Indy10 with Delphi-7 can't download some SSL pages, even with May 2019 DLLs

Tags: delphi, openssl, delphi-7, indy, indy10

I'm working on an old Delphi 7 app that uses Indy 10 to download websites. I'm having difficulty with some, not all, SSL pages.

Version data:

> Indy 10
>
> "libeay32.dll": 1.0.2.19 @ 31-May-19
>
> "ssleay32.dll": 1.0.2.19 @ 31-May-19

When trying to download some pages using SSL (e.g. "https://davisashura.com/"), in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit, which is Rev. 1.8, the following procedure raises the indicated error:

`class procedure EIdOpenSSLAPISSLError.RaiseExceptionCode(const AErrCode, ARetCode: TIdC_INT; const AMsg: String);`
[image]

Initialization code:

```
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;

  with HTTP do begin
    Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)';
    HandleRedirects := True;
    RedirectMaximum := 5;
    ReadTimeout := 20400;
  //Request.AcceptEncoding := 'text/html, deflate, gzip';  // some websites don't download with this set
    Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create;
    IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    HTTPOptions := HTTPOptions + [hoForceEncodeParams, hoInProcessAuth];
  end;
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Off the top of my head (i.e. a wild guess) - Which version of SSL does the site support/require? Is that/those version/versions enabled by default in Indy's OpenSSL implementation?

Comment: I have no idea on either. Since Indy's DLL is May this year, I *assume* it's up-to-date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EOF error simply means the server is closing its end of the socket connection during the TLS handshake, without sending back a TLS alert first. Which means the server doesn't like something in the handshake and is bailing out. The most likely culprit is the TLS version.

By default, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` enables only TLS 1.0, but many sites nowadays require TLS 1.1 or 1.2 instead. You can use the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property to enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

```pascal
HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
HTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)';
HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
HTTP.RedirectMaximum := 5;
HTTP.ReadTimeout := 20400;
//HTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'text/html, deflate, gzip'; // some websites don't download with this set
HTTP.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(HTTP);
HTTP.HTTPOptions := HTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoForceEncodeParams, hoInProcessAuth];

SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP);
SSL SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]; // <-- ADD THIS!
HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
```

There is a TODO item in Indy's issue tracker about this issue:

[#181: Update TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL to enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 by default](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181)

Comment: Thank you. If I enable this, will it still work for TLS 1.0?

Comment: @IamIC yes, because `sslvTLSv1` (TLS 1.0) is included in the set of enabled versions

Comment: Should the other options be enabled? I noticed there are a few more: `sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2`

Comment: @IamIC Nobody uses SSL 2.0 (sslvSSLv2) or 3.0 (sslvSSLv3) anymore, they are old and no longer secure. Don't use them except when needed for legacy systems. Even TLS 1.0 (sslvTLSv1) is starting to be phased out nowadays, but is still in use. sslvSSLv23 is used internally as a wildcard when multiple versions are enabled, you don't need to use it directly.

Comment: Remmy, I implemented your code and it worked on more sites, but I still get a -1 response code for `https://rocketexpansion.com`. Is there something else that could be causing this issue?

Comment: @IamIC "*I still get a -1 response code ...*" - meaning what exactly?

Comment: I mean the HTTP Response code is -1 (instead of 200). Before I used your SSL code, I was getting a -1. Since posting this, I changed the user agent to the same one used by HTTrack, and it works now. Response 200. This appears to be an issue of figuring out which user agent has the broadest acceptance. Which one have you found to work the best?

Comment: @IamIC the ResponseCode should never be -1, that implies the server response is malformed. As for the UserAgent, some servers do not like/accept Indy's default UserAgent, probably because a lot of malwares/bots have been created using Indy over the years, or they are just not coded properly to handle non-browser UserAgents. So yes, sometimes you may run into a server that needs a real browser-like UserAgent to behave correctly